# MVC 5 offline application VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, offline, upshot

I want to create a SPA in visual studio 2013 with MVC 5 capable to work offline and syncronize the data when back online.

I saw there is a template in MVC 4 that work with knockout and upshot but I cannot find the same template in MVC 5.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this course from pluralsight showing how to achieve it: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/html5-offline-apps-angular-indexeddb-bootstrap

Comment: It is not clear if it is about visual studio and MVC

Comment: I believe all .net courses on plural sight use visual studio IDE